# Apply new HTML code into the layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my [Codepen`link`](https://codepen.io/shinva1205/pen/pwEMXx)

I've created a button to show the html code behind a certain area in the layout.

And when I want to edit the code in the textarea such as change the class or add more id... then I press submit to update the new HTML code back into the area but it didn't work and the layout change into a pure HTML code also.

So I don't know if it possible to submit new HTML code back into the layout without reload the page, I'm thinking about apply a form and using AJAX but so far still have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```js
//generate html
$(document).on('click', '.btn-success', function() {
  var target = $('.example-form').find('form');
  $('.bs-example-modal-lg').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var htmlString = $(target).html();
    $("#codeContainer").val(htmlString);
  });
});

//apply new html to layout
$("body").on('click', ".modal.bs-example-modal-lg .btn-primary", function() {
  var htmlcode = $("#codeContainer").val();
  $(".example-form form").html(htmlcode);
});
```

```css
.btn-html {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.example-form {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #343434;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="btn-html">
        <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Show HTML</button>
      </div>
      <div class="example-form">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
            <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
            <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
            </label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Show HTML code behind layout</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <textarea id="codeContainer" rows="25" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you've already loaded the page by the time you're trying to change it so what you have to do is save the markup to local storage or a database somewhere and reload the page

or...

If you're only allowing changes within a certain portion of your page markup, you could use jquery to apply the changes.

Your jquery of

```
//apply new html to layout
$(".btn-primary").click(function () {
  var htmlcode = $("#codeContainer").text();
  $(".example-form form").text(htmlcode);
});
```

looks like you're on the right track to do it this way, however, you're using the wrong method.

Change it to this:

```
//apply new html to layout
$(".btn-primary").click(function () {
  var htmlcode = $("#codeContainer").text();
  $(".example-form form").html(htmlcode);
});
```

Comment: awesome, It solved the problem with the page will turn into a pure HTML code when submit, but it didn't update the new code back into the layout, I've tried to add new class and change old class but the HTML in the layout still remind the same when I press submit.

Comment: my project is similar to those bootstrap builder tool online such as [Frontenda](http://www.frontenda.com/) so I need to make the browser can update the new HTML code when I submit.
There is no other way to do it without reload the page to apply change ?

Comment: if you're trying to permanently update the layout then you'll have to store the changes in some sort of permanent storage like a database. I'm not familiar with Frontenda so I'm afraid I can't help with that.